# Using Bootstrap to style Django Admin Panel

Tags: django, django-admin, django-bootstrap3

I wanted to make my django admin responsive so I'm using twitter's Bootstrap as mentioned everywhere I have gone through following steps:

1. `pip install django-bootstrap3`
2. in installed_apps included bootstrap3
3. `python manage.py collectstatic`

Still I'm not getting my admin responsive.

Answer (score 2):

The django-bootstrap3 plugin doesn't actually make any template changes on its own; it merely makes Bootstrap 3 and some helpful template tags and filters available for use in your templates.  To use bootstrap3 to style the admin site, you can either use a plugin that specifically achieves this, like [this one](https://github.com/django-admin-bootstrap/django-admin-bootstrap) (which I cannot vouch for personally, though it seems fine), or you can [customize your admin templates yourself](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/admin/#overriding-vs-replacing-an-admin-template).

Comment: django-admin-bootstrap is automatically responsive because Bootstrap defaults to it.